# Flutter Making an Image.file() image into an ImageProvider() for zoomable photos

Tags: image, flutter, zooming, offline-browsing

I've created an app that downloads a bunch of information for off-line use, much of which are photos.  In the app, I'd like to use a widget that allows me to have a pan/zoom effect, but the ones I've found don't seem to play well with Image.file() and instead use ImageProviders.

For example, [Photo_View](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) only accepts AssetImage, and NetworkImage images which both inherit from ImageProvider, while Image.file() inherits from Diagnosticable. All of the packages that I've seen operate in basically the same way.

So, my question is how to convert Image.file() data into a ImageProvider format.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of `Image.file()` use `FileImage()` that is type of `ImageProvider`.

From Doc:

> Decodes the given `File` object as an image, associating it with the
>   given scale.
>
> See also:
>
> [`Image.file`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html) for a shorthand of an [`Image`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html) widget backed by [`FileImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html).

I think you can also use `ExactAssetImage` with Image File path(ex: `image.path`) but it should be in `AssetBundle`. Here what doc says about that:

> `ExactAssetImage` class
>
> Fetches an image from an `AssetBundle`, associating it with the given
>   scale.
>
> This implementation requires an explicit final assetName and scale on
>   construction, and ignores the device pixel ratio and size in the
>   configuration passed into resolve. For a resolution-aware variant that
>   uses the configuration to pick an appropriate image based on the
>   device pixel ratio and size, see `AssetImage`.

[read more](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ExactAssetImage-class.html).

Comment: I don't think that ExactAssetImage would work in this case, since it seems like it only works with images that are bundled with the app, and not files that have been downloaded.  HOWEVER, FileImage() worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First import `dart:io;`
then use

```
PhotoView(imageProvider: FileImage(File(path)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

import 'dart:io' as io;

FileImage(io.File(_imageFile!.path)) as ImageProvider

where _imageFile is an XFile

Answer (score 0):

Use **FileImage**(File(imagePath)) widget for showing file image with ImageProvider.